# PHP PDFMerger - Uncaught Error: Class "PDFMerger\exception" not found

Tags: php

I am using the PHP PDFMerger Library: https://github.com/myokyawhtun/PDFMerger

We use this to concatonate customer records into one downloadable PDF.
If there are documents to merge, all works well.
If there are no documents to merge I am getting the following error:

```
UncaughtError: Class "PDFMerger\exception" not found in E:\www\PDFMerger\PDFMerger.php
```

I have found some evidence that this 'may' have something to do with fPDF and FPDI?

Going through the code I can see several instances of 'throw new \exception("message goes here");
but no reference to loading the class or the class itself.

Comment: Make sure you have fPDF and FPDI loaded before you try to create an instance of \Clegginabox\PDFMerger\PDFMerger

Comment: I saw this in the GitHub issues section for the library but this comment is a red herring as there is nothing in the release docs to indicate that fPDF and FPDI are prerequisites. The comments in the library code indicates that the library is based on TCPDF and TCPDI rather than fPDF & FPDI. So adding these manually is a bit odd?

Answer (score 1):

Did some searching and found that no class 'Exception' exists anywhere in the code. Lots of 'extends' but no declaration.

Added the following code to the PHPMerger.php at line 216 (the bottom of the page) :

```
class Exception extends \Exception
{
    public function errorMessage()
    {
        return '<strong>' . htmlspecialchars($this->getMessage()) . "</strong><br />\n";
    }
}
```

That seems to have done the trick. The code still produces a fatal error because there is nothing to combine but at least the error is being handled correctly and the code now works.